# Visual Studio Debug Console faster than command pormpt

Tags: windows, performance-testing, visual-studio-2022

I am working on a performance issue in my multi-threaded application. While testing I noticed consistent drastically different performance depending on how the app was launched.

When I *run without debugging* from within Visual Studio 2022 (Ctrl+F5), my application runs 50% faster than when I launch the same executable with the same command line from the windows command prompt, batch file, or windows run.

Launching in visual studio (good performance), the task manager lists:

- "Visual Studio Debugger Console Application Resources (3)"

  - Appname
  - Console Window Host
  - exe path

Launching from *Window Run* (poor performance) the task manager list:

- Appname (2)

  - Exe-path
  - Console Window Host

I'm wondering what could be different between the two execution environments, and how I could make the command prompt performance equivalent to the debugger console.,

Comment: Do you have some command line parameters, that are set up in project properties? Ctrl+F5 will use these parameters, just like F5.

Comment: The other difference is the current working directory, which is project folder for Ctrl+F5, and .exe folder for Explorer.

Comment: I use $(TargetDir) as the working directory so it is the same, and the command line arguments were cut and paste to be the same.

Comment: Please verify both claims, just in case. When app starts write somewhere both the current working directory and the parameters. The whole environment block might also have some difference. Is this C++ or C# project, or something else?

Comment: it's c++. Just verified both claims. how would I establish the difference in the environment block? I updated the PATH settings that are in the debug settings to no avail.

Comment: there is one setting for "Amp Default Accelerator=WARP software accelerator" that I don't understand and am not sure how to apply the the corresponding setting from the command line. But I toggled that to "C++ AMP runtime default" and the debugger console continued to show better performance.

Comment: For all environment variables there is a function `GetEnvironmentStrings`.